# Closure of an infinite half-open interval

Tags: general-topology

If I have $E = (-\infty, a)$, then $a$ is a boundary point of $E$, and there is no boundary at infinity, so $E \cup a$ a is the closure of $E$. But, $(-\infty, a]$ is half-open, whereas the closure of a set is closed; yet  $[-\infty, a]$ is not permissible. Is this a problem with my notation or with my understanding of something basic? What is correct?

Comment: $(-\infty,a]$ is closed; its complement $(a,\infty)$ is open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that every topological space is *closed in itself*. So is $\Bbb R=(-\infty, \, \infty)$. 
So, the closure of $(-\infty,\, a)$ is indeed $(-\infty, a]$.

However, if we work on the *extended* real line $\bar{\Bbb R}=\Bbb R\cup\{-\infty, \, \infty\}$, then its closure will be $[-\infty, \, a] $.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping something like that was the case!

Answer (score 1):

$(-\infty,a]$ is a closed set in the usual topology of $\Bbb R$.  It includes all of its limit points.  The more general definition of a closed set is that it is the complement of an open set.  As $(a,\infty)$ is open, its complement $(-\infty,a]$ is closed.

Comment: Yes, I was also worried about the complement issue. Thank you.